# how do I return two JSON arrays from an .ajax Call?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, servlets

I'm using jqPlot and since I can't find one decent place to find out how to send multiple series to jqplot through JSON, I will try to work around it.

*so here's a little background:*

Right now, I can call my servlet and return a JSON array with the data that I'm going to display in the chart.

**AJAX CALL**

```
$.ajax({
            type:   'POST',
            cache:  'false',
            data:   params,             
            url:    '/miloWeb/PlotChartServlet',
            async:  false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(series){                  
                coordinates =  [series] ;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(ajaxOptions);
            }   
        });
```

**SERVLET**

```
    private void generateCoordinates(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

    JSONArray coordinates = new JSONArray();
    try {
        coordinates = findChartCoordinatesByPatientPK();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.getOutputStream().print(coordinates.toString());

}
```

What this does is return the string:

> [["07/06/2000","22.0"],["08/06/2000","20.0"],["08/06/2003","15.0"],["08/06/2005","35.0"],["08/06/2007","12.0"],["08/06/2010","10.0"],["08/06/2012","10.0"]]

So I store that in the variable 'coordinates' and use those to plot the jqPlot graph using:

```
var plot10 = $.jqplot ('chartdiv', coordinates);
```

*Up To this point everything works great, now comes what I'm trying to achieve:*

If I hardcode a String that symbolizes the two arrays inside another array, like so:

```
[[["07/06/2000","22.0"],["08/06/2000","20.0"],["08/06/2003","15.0"],["08/06/2005","35.0"],["08/06/2007","12.0"],["08/06/2010","10.0"],["08/06/2012","10.0"]], [["07/06/2000","21.0"],["08/06/2000","19.0"],["08/06/2003","14.0"],["08/06/2005","34.0"],["08/06/2007","11.0"],["08/06/2010","9.0"],["08/06/2012","9.0"]]]
```

I can get the jQplot to plot the two distinct lines in the chart! So I tried doing the same and returning a String exactly like that one through the servlet:

**NOT WORKING SERVLET**

```
    private void generateCoordinates(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        JSONArray coordinates = new JSONArray();
        JSONArray coordinates2 = new JSONArray();
        try {
            coordinates = VitalsBB.findChartCoordinatesByPatientPK();
            coordinates2 = VitalsBB.findChartCoordinatesByPatientPK2();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.getOutputStream().print( coordinates.toString() + ", " + coordinates2.toString());

    }
```

But that doesn't work, it gives me a parse Error. So do I need to modify the AJAX call? or is there a way to give back two `JSON arrays.toString()` to my form and store them in a variable? Or maybe I need two variables?

Comment: Did you try wrapping the output with `'['` and `']'`? Notice that you need this for it to be a JSON array.

Comment: that was IT, hourse spent on something soooooooo basic. THANK YOU

Comment: If it works before, and you change something, always check where you just made the change in logic. It is likely the culprit code :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not enclosing the two sub-arrays in outer array brackets when you call `response.getOutputStream().print()`.

Try this instead:

```
response.getOutputStream().print("[" + coordinates.toString() + ", " + coordinates2.toString() + "]");
```

If your code worked when you hardcoded the array, then this should work.

Comment: Thanks pb2q, that was it, I am so grateful!